# Microsoft Dynamics 365 Portal "Invalid sign-in attempt" error

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, powerapps, power-automate, dynamics-crm-portals

For Portal Registration/Login (using Local Login), we're inviting contacts using 'Create Invitation'.

Users are receiving the invitation email and on-click of the link they will land on the Redeem Invitation page. When the user clicks on the register button in the portal and when the user provides the information like username, password etc. Users are able to login perfectly.

But, if try to login using the sign-in option with their Username/Email and Password then it always fail with 'Invalid sign-in attempt'.

How to resolve this 'Invalid sign-in attempt'?

I tried by checking the power portal settings, clearing the cache and all the available solutions on the net.

Answer (score 0):

I found that my users were using their email address to login instead of the username that they created after receiving the invitation, thus, their logins were failing in the same way as yours. Kind of strange that the portal makes you use a username when 99% of systems use an email address as the login username, so this confuses everyone, including me!